# How to find files by names which contains brackets?

Tags: linux, shell, find

I have files with names like this:

`level(basic)-[done]1.txt`
`level(basic)-[done]1.pdf`
`level(basic)-[done]1.doc`

I need to find all of them by name.

`find * -type f -name 'level(basic)-[done]1.*'`

This command doesn't work. How can i escape metacharacters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
find * -type f -name 'level(basic)-\[done\]1.*'
```

That is, escaping each `[` with `\[`. `(` does not need to be escaped, at least on my Ubuntu 12.

Comment: Thanks! It was so easy. I tried almost all types of escaping but not this way.

Comment: @Rysiu: Both the shell and the `find` command expand wildcards, using special characters like `*`, `?`, `[`, and `]`. (`find` is unlike most  Unix utilities in this way; most of them just take the arguments passed to them by the shell and treat them as literal strings or file names.)